# WMI error in unlicensed Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wmi

I'm installing a TFS2010 server and I'm getting a WMI error in the analysis services check (ACCESS_DENIED), since the analysis services is in a different server I ask the sysadmin guy (I'm a developer) to add the installer account to the local administrators temporally, he did but now I'm getting this:

> [ Reporting ] TF255437: An error
>   occurred while querying the Windows
>   Management Instrumentation (WMI)
>   interface on the following computer:
>   [SERVER].  The following error message
>   was received: .

As you can see the error is a joke, since now I'm an administrator I checked the machine and the WMI Service is running and WMI Compatibility for IIS 6 is enabled.

One thing I noticed though is that the license for the server expired, (I guess the sysadmin forgot to activate the server), this could be the reason WMI is failing?, if so, there is any documentation about it?, I don't want to tell the sysadmin, "hey I just logged on in your server and I think you should activate it".

Thanks

Comment: Did you log out and then back into after the permissions change?

Comment: and you did a runas administrator on the tfs2010 install correct?

Comment: yes I did runas during install, I did not log out, i will try that

Comment: I log out but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I noticed though is that the license for the server expired, (I guess the sysadmin forgot to activate the server), this could be the reason WMI is failing?

Yes.

**Edit: Eating my own hat here. The answer is actually [No](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/WS08-product-activation.aspx).**

> If you have not activated Windows Server 2008, you are reminded each time you log in and at common intervals until the end of the activation grace period of 60* days. If you have not activated Windows Server 2008 during this grace period, the system then will be unlicensed. Persistent notifications will alert you of the need to activate. While in the notification condition, you will be able to log on and off, and the system will function normally. However, the desktop background will change to black, and Windows Update installs only critical updates. The notifications will continue until you activate the operating system.

Comment: hmm never had activation cause wmi access denied errors, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: If that's not why I think I should check elsewhere on the server.

Comment: Check your remote credentials and ensure you're authenticating correctly with the remote server. It'll probably need a qualified account name e.g. yourdomain\tfsadmin to reach it. If you just go with 'tfsadmin', or you're using local accounts, it may not be happy. Check Windows firewall is off on the server.